# How to add arbitrary files to my custom Debian Installer image

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I want to add files that will be used at the end of the install via `preseed/late_command`. Those will be a script that will get executed as well as some files the script will use.

At the moment, I have a checkout of debian-installer package and can build the netboot iso with `make build_netboot` (from within `build` subdirectory).

Comment: I guess you can mount the iso, add the files you want, and then close up the iso. Are you looking for the details of how to do that, or did I miss the point of your question?

Comment: I would like to avoid taking that hacky path, and rather have it on the iso by the time I run `make build_netboot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a local config override file and use `EXTRAFILES` variable to specify those files, example (assuming you are inside `build/` on debian-installer checkout):

```
echo 'EXTRAFILES = script.sh file1.txt file.json' > config/local
```

From there on, build the netboot iso:

```
make build_netboot
```

Answer (score 1):

You needn't rebuild anything (at least for this) if you start the installer via Syslinux (or extlinux or isolinux or pxelinux): this family of boot loaders can handle multiple initramfs images and you get the union of them as the installer file system. So just put all the needed files in a directory, enter it and do something like

```
find -print0 | cpio --create --format=newc --owner 0:0 --null --quiet | gzip -9n >../overlay.cpio.gz
```

Then copy `overlay.cpio.gz` next to `initrd.gz` of the installer and change the relevant `APPEND` line to contain `initrd=initrd.gz,overlay.cpio.gz`.

Comment: Would that be the initrd in `build/dest/netboot/debian-installer/amd64`?

Comment: Probably. But I'd just use the text- or GTK-mode one from the *debian-installer-8-netboot-amd64* package (as appropriate).

Comment: How do I turn it into an iso file?

Comment: Use `genisoimage` or `xorriso` as detailed at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD. Basically, it all comes down to following the [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=ISOLINUX) instructions with modern tools.